# c++ call template class specialization member function

Tags: c++

I am new in C++ and I am trying to implement template class specialization member functions.
Here is the code which I did:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
using std::string;


namespace std {
template <> struct number_limits<Second> {
    using val_type = Second::value_type;

    public:
        val_type fmin() {
            return Second::min_val();
        }
        val_type fmax() {
            return Second::max_val();
        }
};
}


class Borders {};
class Second {
public:
    using value_type = short;
private:
    value_type n = min_val();
public:
    Second() = default;
    value_type valeur() const noexcept {
        return n;
    }
    static value_type min_val() noexcept {
        return 0;
    }
    static value_type max_val() noexcept {
        return 59;
    }

    static value_type prochaine(value_type m) {
        return m == max_val() ? m % max_val() : m + 1;
    }

    Second(value_type val) {
        if (val < min_val() || val > max_val()) {
            throw Borders{};
        }
    }


};

int main()
{
    number_limits<Second> test;

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it, i am getting the list of the errors:

[image]

Please give me suggestions how I can make template class "number_limits" correctly and how I could call function fmax() of this class from main() function?

Comment: The first suggestion: copy-paste the error messages as text, not image, take the whole error messages from the output window, not the error list.

Comment: What is Second in the beginning?

Comment: You have a number of errors: `Second` isn't defined before it's use;  the class `number_limits` cannot be specialized without a primary template. There is no class `number_limits` in the `std` namespace. Are you trying to specialize `std::numeric_limits`? If so, you would need to include `<limits>`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,cjignatius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend researching classes in C++ more before coming back to this problem. I also would recommend not messing with namespaces yet as a beginner as they're only really useful when working in large teams of developers and only make the code harder to understand when used correctly. It doesn't seem like you quite understand what classes are and how they work, so here's a quick rundown about the basics of classes to get you started.

## Classes

#### 1. Why are they useful?

Classes, similar to structures, help us to organize data and its related functions. Classes and structures share the same basic structure (no pun intended) but classes build on structures in many ways. When making a class you want to put some related data in the class as well as functions that operate on that data. This helps organize your code better, makes sure that only the function in that class can change the data, and helps with debugging, since it narrows down the culprit of a break or bug.

#### 2. Classes in C++

Here's a simple example class to show the syntax:

```
class myClass {
public:
    myClass(int x, int y, int z) { a = x; b = y; c = z; }
    int add() { return a + b + c; }
    int getA() { return a; }
    int setA(int newA) { a = newA; }
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

Some things to note are that the public and private access modifiers should only be listed once and everything that is public or private should be under that modifier. Doing otherwise is bad practice.

## Your Code

I'm not really sure why you're using a structure of templated type class, but regardless that is not the correct syntax. Templates should be defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class myClass{};
```

The first line is not required to be on a separate line. The syntax is rigid except for T, which can be any identifier you wish to represent the templated type. When you are defining your structure, you're explicitly stating the type as , which undermines the purpose of templates. However, if you want the template to contain a default type, you could do as follows:

```
template <typename T = Second>
```

As you're defining whatever it is you're templating, whether or be a class, structure, or function, write the function **exactly** as you would normally except replace any type declarations of your templated type with the given template identifier, in this case 'T'. I would strongly recommend not going the structure route for this class, however, and you really shouldn't need a template for what you are trying to do here.

There are a lot of other improvements you could make here, but hopefully this should help you get on the right track. If you're confused about anything at all in programming it's better to research and read up. You should be able to explain to even a non-programmer why every line of code you write is there and what it does in order to write great code.